# Display my Select List Items in ShortDateString format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I have a model with a SelectList property that will contain multiple dates as its values.  I want to display these values without the timestamp added.  How can I show these dates in shortdatetime format?  I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class EditWeightsViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Associates")]
    public SelectList AssociatesList { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Week")]
    public SelectList WeeksOfEntryList { get; set; }

    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Here's part of my controller (*Note, weeks is a List of DateTimes):

```
editWeightsViewModel.WeeksOfEntryList = new SelectList(weeks.Select(item => new SelectListItem
{
   Selected = false,
   Value = item.ToString(),
   Text = item.ToShortDateString()
}));
```

My dropdownlist is showing `System.Web.MVC.SelectListItem` instead of the actual dates.  What am I doing wrong?  Am I wrong to go about it this way?  Would it be easier to create an editor template that displays this in ShortDateTime format?

Comment: What's going wrong? The dates are not being displayed in ShortDate format? How are they being displayed?

Comment: You neglected to tell us what actual problem you're experiencing. The code you have looks fine.

Comment: I said that my dropdownlist is showing `System.Web.MVC.SelectListItem` instead of the actual dates.  Sorry, I guess it was kind of vague.

Answer (score 0):

`Html.DropDownListFor` helper method's second argument is a collection of `SelectListItem`. So change the type of `WeeksOfEntryList` property to a list of `SelectListItem`. I also added another property, `SelectedWeek` to store the selected option value.

```
public class EditWeightsViewModel
{
    public string SelectedWeek {set;get;}

    [DisplayName("Week")]
    public List<SelectListItem> WeeksOfEntryList { get; set; }          

    [DisplayName("Associates")]
    public SelectList AssociatesList { get; set; }

    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
}
```

And when you load the `WeeksOfEntryList`  property value of your viewmodel.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new EditWeightsViewModel();
  vm.WeeksOfEntryList = weeks.Select(s=> new SelectListItem
                       { Value=s.ToShortDateString(),
                         Text=s.ToShortDateString()}).ToList();
  //If you want to keep one option selected, Set the vm.SelectedWeek property value.


  return View(vm);
}
```

And in your razor view,

```
@using YourNameSpaceHere.EditWeightsViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedWeek, Model.WeeksOfEntryList ,"Select")
```

Comment: This seems to have worked.  Any idea why my version doesn't work?

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla, Because you creating a (pointless) second SelectList from the first (inner SelectList) but not setting the Value and Text properties.